# jQuery drop down menu close open topics

Tags: jquery

Please see http://www.laerdalmail.com/dev/discoversimulation/needs/# for an example of the menu in question:
When a topic is clicked, and a sub menu drops down, is it possible to have any other open topic automatically close? Below, I have included the function that handles the dropdown for review.

```
function Reveal(a, orig_height) {
    var ul = a.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul").item(0);

    $(ul).animate({
        height: 'toggle',
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 'slow', function() {
        if ($(ul.parentNode).height() < orig_height) {
            $(a).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
        }
    });
}​
```

Comment: Interesting mix of jQuery and vanilla JS you've got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close all parents at the start of your function, then open the one triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the [jquery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), it would make it a lot easier for you, and the animations are much smoother